# HTTP digest authentication fail due to wrong nonce-count in iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, http, authentication, nsurlsession

HTTP digest authentication no longer works in our app since iOS 10 due to wrong nonce-count in Authorization: Digest header generated by NSURLSession.

The same code works in iOS 9, but fail to auth in iOS 10

1. Create a POST request with NSURLRequest
2. Fire it with NSURLSession
3. Handle NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest in `urlSession(_:didReceive:completionHandler:)` delegate
4. The server responds with a 401 and qop="auth" string as expected
5. The app requests again with the Authorization: Digest header set.

   According to [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt):

   > nonce-count
   >
   > This MUST be specified if a qop directive is sent (see above), and
   >   MUST NOT be specified if the server did not send a qop directive in
   >   the WWW-Authenticate header field. The nc-value is the hexadecimal
   >   count of the number of requests (including the current request)
   >   that the client has sent with the nonce value in this request. For
   >   example, in the first request sent in response to a given nonce
   >   value, the client sends "nc=00000001". The purpose of this
   >   directive is to allow the server to detect request replays by
   >   maintaining its own copy of this count - if the same nc-value is
   >   seen twice, then the request is a replay. See the description
   >   below of the construction of the request-digest value.

   However, the nonce-count start at "nc=00000002" even for the first request in iOS 10, which cause the server to reject it.
6. Expect server response 200 OK

**iOS 9 & Before:**

```
POST /Tunnel/Message.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.18.70.12:3454
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/xml
User-Agent: iViewer/1 CFNetwork/758.5.3 Darwin/15.6.0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: 
AuthType: digest
Accept-Language: zh-tw
Content-Length: 69
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="ND8422P", 
nonce="cc17a78cdd96d54e012eadefe7d13d82", uri="/Tunnel/Message.aspx", 
response="51587db4bcf6eeece68c4ec21108f170", 
cnonce="47b8df8a980f280038834b7817250e90", nc=00000001, qop="auth"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GetServerInfo></GetServerInfo>

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 1127
```

**iOS 10:**

```
POST /Tunnel/Message.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.18.70.12:3454
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/xml
User-Agent: iViewer/1 CFNetwork/808.0.2 Darwin/16.0.0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: 
AuthType: digest
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Length: 69
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="ND8422P", 
nonce="4b8bf8549da0c3010f031472e95f387d", uri="/Tunnel/Message.aspx", 
response="91cf44bc0aadf2f743164d03b5c708c7", 
cnonce="b5f9e6c69e19c1b396298d68f2aefe7e", nc=00000002, qop="auth"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GetServerInfo></GetServerInfo>

HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth", realm="ND8422P", nonce="8e8b0538bb08876ac4d8203f1d14e9ac"
CSeq: 0
```

Is anyone facing the same issue?

The only related post I could find is:
[Apple Developer Forums : Problem of the digest authentication](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50617), but no further information.

How do you fix it or get workaround on client app side without asking server side to ignore the wrong nonce-count?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Developer Technical Support confirm that is a bug of iOS 10.
Hope it will be fixed soon.

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). 
>   We believe this issue is a bug. Please file a bug report using the Bug Reporter tool https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.

Update:
Apple fixed this issue in iOS 10.2 Beta 3

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, the OS is sending a HEAD request first, and your server-side code isn't getting it.  I would try running Charles Proxy to verify that this is what's happening.

That said, skipping a nonce count is not inherently an indication of any sort of attack.  It could occur even in iOS 9 if a request got lost somehow (e.g. a network error).  What's important is to ensure that the count doesn't go backwards.  So I would argue that your server code is buggy and should not be rejecting that to begin with.

Comment: You're right. Skipping a nonce count is a bad idea. Although the iOS 10 did sent the first auth request start from nc=00000002, which was just confirmed as a a bug by Apple engineer. We found that our server code might reject any auth request which was not start from nc=00000001, this could be buggy as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem in our company as described here:
[Cordova app can't connect with Dynamics NAV Web-Service (ODATA) after update to iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148678/cordova-app-cant-connect-with-dynamics-nav-web-service-odata-after-update-to)

We can reproduce the issue both in our App and the Safari Browser with iOS 10 devices. There does not seem to be a simple client side workaround. We opened a Bug Report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the problem was solved with the 10.2 Beta release.

Comment: Here too. Looks fixed in iOS 10.2 Beta 3