# iOS 10 HTTP digest authentication fail in AVPlayer (even on 10.2 beta3)

Tags: ios, avplayer

The similar topic on SO are:
[HTTP digest authentication fail due to wrong nonce-count in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587003/http-digest-authentication-fail-due-to-wrong-nonce-count-in-ios-10)

And it looks more like the symptom mentioned here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50617
but still has no answer.

We use AVPlayer to perform the digest authentication, and it's working on iOS 9.

What we capture from Wireshark is below:

**iOS9**

```
GET /SD/TestContentsforAndroid/Fireworks.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.40.1:8081
X-Playback-Session-Id: FE21C8D7-9603-4FDE-A648-7544440BD820
Range: bytes=0-1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13A405 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 9_0_1 like Mac OS X; zh_tw)
Accept-Language: zh-tw
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Drive", nonce="a56fa5b58b55f5d780fdc2e6232c64b2", qop="auth"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 351
Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2016 03:26:56 GMT
Server: lighttpd

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>401 - Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 - Unauthorized</h1>
 </body>
</html>
GET /SD/TestContentsforAndroid/Fireworks.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.40.1:8081
Authorization: Digest username="admin", realm="Drive", nonce="a56fa5b58b55f5d780fdc2e6232c64b2", uri="/SD/TestContentsforAndroid/Fireworks.mp4", response="a98e31641aa3930d1eb907dcc9a17963", cnonce="afbc1d37b0fd1302948f8554b7400f30", nc=00000002, qop="auth"
X-Playback-Session-Id: FE21C8D7-9603-4FDE-A648-7544440BD820
Range: bytes=0-1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13A405 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 9_0_1 like Mac OS X; zh_tw)
Accept-Language: zh-tw
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: video/mpeg
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1312277247"
Last-Modified: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 06:18:08 GMT
Content-Range: bytes 0-1/131067666
Content-Length: 2
Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2016 03:26:56 GMT
Server: lighttpd

....ftypmp42....isommp42....moov...lmvhd.....U5..U5....X....................................................@...................................iods.......O..)......trak...\tkhd....|%...U5.............................................................@........8.....[mdia... mdhd....|%...U5.........U......-hdlr........vide............VideoHandler.....minf....vmhd...............$dinf....dref............url ........stbl....stsd............avc1...........................8.H...H...............................................0avcC.d.(....gd.(.
```

Which seems follow RFC standards,
however on iOS 10.2 beta 3

**iOS10.2 beta 3**

```
GET /SD/DemoData/TestContentsforAndroid/Fireworks.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.40.1:8081
X-Playback-Session-Id: 82E92AFC-FC64-4142-AE04-A1E422B92E75
Range: bytes=0-1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.14C5077b (iPhone; U; CPU OS 10_2 like Mac OS X; zh_tw)
Accept-Language: zh-tw
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Drive", nonce="a1c413ee966f67b1c8e0e44af227335c", qop="auth"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 351
Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2016 03:39:02 GMT
Server: lighttpd

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>401 - Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 - Unauthorized</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

The server does not receive any further request from AVPlayer on iOS 10.

At first I thought it has same root cause due to wrong nonce-count,
but it seems different.

By the way, change the auth method to BASIC can bypass the problem, but it does not solve the digest issue.

Anyone facing same issue and have other ideas to workaround?
I don't know if Apple noticed this yet.

Update: 20170309

Apple's bug report system change my report to below.

29381646 AVPlayer http digest authentication fail on iOS10+

State: Closed                   Product:

### Rank: No Value

### Duplicate of 29218533 (Open or Closed; log in to see the actual state)

However, seems I don't have permission to access 29218533,
so I am unable to track the actual response from Apple now.